# Figure of Merit for sizing P-MOS and N-MOS in Inverter circuit

Tags: analog, inverter, cmos, cadence, virtuoso

I am trying to design a basic circuit block of inverter (Analog circuit) in Cadence Virtuoso schematic in 22nm technology. It will be used for non-overlapping clock generator. I need to size the P-MOS and N-MOS. To choose a preliminary size, I can do parametric simulation of varying W with minimum L in DC analysis and transient analysis for desired delay. What figure of merit should I look into to choose the size? Should I look into DC analysis simulation where the graph (VTC) cuts the middle of input clock voltage for falling edge? Or is there any other way through simulation to decide for the sizes except going to the layout phase which comes later after full circuit simulation?

Comment: How well do you understand the load? In most cases, the routing of the output of such an inverter has majority of the impact on the signal as seen at the load. The signal may be just fine on the inverter output, but add long wires on the chip and things go south pretty quickly. Designing that inverter in isolation from fan-out and its routing is futile. Start with something that can drive load capacitance through zero inductance well enough, then see what routing inductance and distributed capacitance will do to it. Expect it to do a lot.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the load and the inverters in delay buffer. Now i have to go for equal fall and rise time with trying out different sizing. Thanks for your answer though